# NextInt giving Force close

Tags: java, android, random

Whenever I try to execute this it gives me FC on my application

```
int a, b;
Random s = new Random();
    if (diffi.contains("easy") && name.contains("sub")) {
        a = s.nextInt(21);
        b = s.nextInt(a);
    }
```

But when remove "a " and put a number in its place then it starts working

```
int a, b;
Random s = new Random();
    if (diffi.contains("easy") && name.contains("sub")) {
        a = s.nextInt(21);
        b = s.nextInt(21);
    }
```

I want the second number "b" to be smaller than a in all cases

Comment: *"I want the second number "b" to be smaller than a in all cases"* The code in your first code sample, provided `a` and `b` are both declared and both `int`, does that.

Comment: force close. I think I tagged android for the question.

Comment: @user2479697: Gotcha. Still worth actually typing it out. :-)

Comment: Show us where are the variables `a` and `b` initialized.

Comment: @user2479697 *initialized*, not *declared*

Comment: @user2479697 post the exception details from then logcat, it will make things more clear to understand

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll get an exception if the first call to `nextInt` returns 0. Then the second call *can't* return a value which is greater than or equal to 0 but less than 0, hence the exception.

From the docs for `Random.nextInt`:

> **Throws:** `IllegalArgumentException` - if `n` is not positive

You should step back for a moment though, and work out why your diagnostic approach didn't actually see those exception details. Did you check the application logs? I'd expect the exception to be clear, with the right exception, which would then make it fairly obvious what was wrong.

EDIT: I very much doubt that it's actually throwing an exception *whenever* that code is executed. Instead, I suspect that *either* that code is executing many times (so eventually you'll see that `a` is 0 and the exception will be thrown) *or* you've just been unlucky.

Comment: But why "***Whenever*** *I try to execute...*"?

Comment: Seems like I had a bad coincidence then :P

Comment: Your `nextInt()` returned 0's just to get Skeet's attention... :D